# How to fetch all records using DBI from MSSQL

Tags: ruby, dbi

I am using `ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-linux]` along with these gems. I have a simple DBI script that displays the DisplayNames, however **the output from the script does not match the output in the Database**. The output from the script fetches the last record and displays it 10 times.

My DSN is pointing to a MSSQL database.

```
#/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbi'

oConn = DBI.connect('DBI:ODBC:DSN','username','password')
query=oConn.prepare("select top 10 DisplayName from table")

query.execute
@rows=query.fetch_all
puts @rows.size

@rows.each do |r|
  puts r["DisplayName"].to_s
end

puts "done"
query.finish
oConn.disconnect
```

The installed gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
activerecord-informix-adapter (1.1.1)
activerecord-odbc-adapter (2.0)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.10)
activeresource (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
builder (3.0.4, 3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
commonjs (0.2.6)
daemon_controller (1.1.4)
dbd-odbc (0.2.5)
dbi (0.4.5)
deprecated (2.0.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
haml (3.1.6)
hike (1.2.2, 1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1, 0.6.0)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.3, 1.5.5)
less (2.2.2)
less-rails (2.2.6)
libv8 (3.3.10.4 x86_64-linux)
mail (2.5.4)
mime-types (1.23)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.7.3, 1.3.6)
passenger (4.0.4, 4.0.0.rc6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5, 1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3, 1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2, 0.6.1)
rails (3.2.13)
railties (3.2.13, 3.2.3)
rake (10.0.4, 0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12, 3.9.5)
ruby-informix (0.8.0)
ruby-odbc (0.99994)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
sass (3.1.20)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
simple_form (2.0.4)
sprockets (2.2.2, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
therubyracer (0.10.1)
thor (0.18.1, 0.14.6)
tilt (1.4.1, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.6, 2.2.1)
tzinfo (0.3.37, 0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.6)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_record
    begin
        record = CONN.prepare( " SELECT * FROM questions " )
        record.execute()
        record.map { |row| printf "ID : %d, description : %s, marks : %d, category : %s \n", row[0], row[1], row[2] , row[3] }
    rescue  DBI::DatabaseError => e
        puts "Error code : #{e.err}"
        puts "Error message : #{e.errstr}"
    end

end
```

CONN is a constant that is holding the connection
like `CONN = Connection.new.create_connection`
i did DBI connection. that is require DBI gem instollation along with driver vender # specific i am using DBD-mysql so its working fine.